# Maven custom archive extension - how do I use unpack-dependencies?

Tags: maven, maven-2, unpack, maven-dependency-plugin

I have a custom artfiact type `web-module`; just a ZIP but with a custom extension.

I then have a project depending on it, I want its dependencies of this custom type to be unpacked. The [maven-dependency-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin) [unpack-dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/unpack-dependencies-mojo.html) goal seemed to fit the bill, however I keep getting the error:

```
[INFO] Unknown archiver type
Embedded error: No such archiver: 'web-module'.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Unknown archiver type
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:719)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:556)
    ...
```

I've done some [Googling](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Problems-with-register-new-archive-type-td4574907.html) and understood that I can specifiy a custom unarchiver type in my custom plugin's *components.xml*. The following is now in my *components.xml*:

```
<component>
  <role>org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.UnArchiver</role>
  <role-hint>web-module</role-hint>
  <implementation>org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.zip.ZipUnArchiver</implementation>
  <instantiation-strategy>per-lookup</instantiation-strategy>
</component>
```

Once an install of my custom plugin was performed I tried again, still no luck! Anyone know where I'm going wrong?

I have also tried adding the custom extension plugin to the erroring module's POM with `<extensions>true</extensions>`.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
<component-set>
    <components>
        <!-- Life-cycle mappings -->
        <component>
            <role>org.apache.maven.lifecycle.mapping.LifecycleMapping</role>
            <role-hint>web-module</role-hint>
             <implementation>org.apache.maven.lifecycle.mapping.DefaultLifecycleMapping</implementation>
            <configuration>
                <phases>
                    <!-- You might need these as well. -->
                </phases>
            </configuration>
        </component>

        <!-- Artifact Handlers -->
        <component>
            <role>org.apache.maven.artifact.handler.ArtifactHandler</role>
            <role-hint>web-module</role-hint>
            <implementation>org.apache.maven.artifact.handler.DefaultArtifactHandler</implementation>
            <configuration>
                <extension>web-module</extension>
                <type>web-module</type>
                <packaging>web-module</packaging>
            </configuration>
        </component>
    </components>
</component-set>
```