# Which formats can the dependencies:unpack-dependencies goal unpack?

Tags: maven, maven-dependency-plugin

Which archive formats can `dependencies:unpack-dependencies` unpack? For instance, as far as I see it can't unpack RPM packages. Is there a list of formats it supports available somewhere? Is there some trick with which I can make maven unpack RPM package?

Comment: Maybe an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393110/maven-custom-archive-extension-how-do-i-use-unpack-dependencies

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Maven Dependency Plugin uses internally Plexus Archiver to archive and unarchive files. As of today, version 2.10 of the `maven-dependency-plugin` [depends on version 2.9](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/maven/plugins/tags/maven-dependency-plugin-2.10/pom.xml) of [`plexus-archiver`](https://github.com/codehaus-plexus/plexus-archiver/tree/plexus-archiver-2.9).

Plexus components are configured with the help of a `META-INF/plexus/components.xml` file. In the case of the Dependency Plugin, you can see this file [in the source code](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/maven/plugins/tags/maven-dependency-plugin-2.10/src/main/resources/META-INF/plexus/components.xml) and it declares unarchiver for the following extensions: `zip`, `jar`, `war`, `ear`, `swc`, `nar`, `esb`, `sar`, `car`, `par`, `rar`. They all use the same `ZipUnArchiver` component, meaning they are all extracted as if they were ZIP files.

Plexus Archiver 2.9 also comes with its set of predefined unarchiver, and it adds: `bzip2`, `gzip`, `tar`, `tgz`, `tar.gz`, `tbz2`, `tar.bz2` to the list. Latest version also adds `snappy` and `xz` files.

---

If you want to be able to unpack a custom extension, you will need to create a new project capable of unpacking it and register it as a Plexus component. For RPM packages, you can create a `rpm-archiver` Maven project and have the following inside `META-INF/plexus/components.xml`:

```
<component-set>
  <components>
    <component>
      <role>org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.UnArchiver</role>
      <role-hint>rpm</role-hint>
      <implementation>class.able.to.unpack.rpm.packages</implementation>
      <instantiation-strategy>per-lookup</instantiation-strategy>
    </component>
  </components>
</component-set>
```

where `class.able.to.unpack.rpm.packages` is the fully classified name of your custom class able to unpack RPM files. This class must implement the interface `org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.UnArchiver`, but to simplify, you can make this class inherit from `org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractUnArchiver`. All you need to do is then override the `execute()` and `execute(path, outputDirectory)` methods. The former needs to extract the file retrieved by `getSourceFile()` into the directory retrieved by `getDestDirectory()`, while the latter only extract the specified `path` inside the source file into the given `outputDirectory`.

After compiling and installing this new project, you can add it as a dependency to the `maven-dependency-plugin`:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.10</version>
    <!-- rest of your configuration -->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>my.archiver</groupId>
            <artifactId>rpm-archiver</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

This way, when the plugin runs, it will know how to unpack files having the `rpm` extension, and will use the class you configured in `components.xml`.